# How to install moodle properly into xampp

Tags: moodle

Hai i am trying to install moodle into my system using xampp server.

But i am having the error like below:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in D:\xampp\htdocs\moodel\server\moodle\config.php on line 5
```

But the installation in successfully completed. why this problem occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this at the top of `config.php`?

```
<?php

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();
```

Comment: No it is not not available in my config.php. what i want to do just copy your above and paste it into my config.php